# Verifying row is not empty before adding new row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm developing a tool which is supposed to save the content from a `JTable` to a CSV file, I have this "add row" button to add a new row, but I need the last row to be filled on every cell and then be allowed to add a new row.

Here is the code I have, but this doesn't create the new row nor throw any errors on console.

```
 private void btnAddRowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    for(int i=0;i<=jTable1.getColumnCount();i++){
        if(jTable1.isRowSelected(jTable1.getRowCount())){
           do{
              model.insertRow(jTable1.getRowCount(), new Object[]{});
           } while(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getRowCount(), i).equals(""));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loops don't make sense.  You're inserting a new row for each column in the table model, also, you'll find that the last row is `getRowCount() - 1`

Comment: So, what you're saying is, the user can't be allowed to add a new row until the last row is filled...?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking this post and I used the code posted by MadProgrammer, but I made a few modifications and I got this working properly according to your need. If you want you can ask me for the project and I can happily provide it to you

```
private void btnAddRowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    boolean rowCompleted;
    int lastRow = jTable1.getRowCount()-1;
    if(jTable1.isRowSelected(lastRow)){
        for(int col=0;col<jTable1.getColumnCount();col++){
            Object value = jTable1.getValueAt(lastRow, col);
            if(value == null || value.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                rowCompleted=false;
            }
            else{
                rowCompleted=true;
            }
            if(rowCompleted==true){
                model.insertRow(jTable1.getRowCount(), new Object[]{});
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went worng. Try this:\n - Please select a row before adding new row.\n - Please verify there are no empty cells","Processing table's data",1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong. Verify this:\n - There is not any row selected.\n - You can only create new rows after last row","Processing table's data",1);
    }

}
```

I hope this could help you, but first say thanks to MadProgrammer :D

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so what you seem to be saying is, the user should not be allowed to add a new row until the last row is fully completed...

You existing loop doesn't make sense, basically, for each column, you are checking to see if the last row is selected, and inserting a new row for each column which is blank (`""`)...?

Remember, generally Java is zero indexed, this means, the last row is actually `jTable1.getRowCount() - 1`, so, it's unlikely that your `if isRowSelected` would be true, which is actually a good thing, cause otherwise you would have had a real mess...

Assuming I understand your question correctly (as it's a little vague), you could try something more like this...

```
boolean rowCompleted = true;
int lastRow = jTable1.getRowCount() - 1;
if (jTable1.isRowSelected(lastRow)) {
    for (int col = 0; col < jTable1.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        Object value = jTable.getValueAt(lastRow, col);
        if (value == null || value.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            rowCompleted = false;
            break;
        }
    } 
}

if (rowCompleted) {
    // Insert new row...
} else {
    // Show error message
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use a `TableModelListener`.

Every time a cell is updated on the last row of the table you check to make sure all columns have data. If all columns have data you enable the "Add Row" button, otherwise you disenable the button.